# Replacing Negatives integers in array with zero and making another array to store the numbers excluding all the zeroes

Tags: java, arrays

The type of input should be like `1, -9 ,6, -7, -4, 3`
and there should be 2 outputs. First one `1 0 6 0 0 3`
and second one `1 6 3`:

```
import java.util.*;

class pr9 {
    public static void calc() {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x,i;
        System.out.println("Enter Length of the Array");
        x=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[x];
        int b[]=new int [x];
        for(i=0;i<x;i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter " +x+" Numbers");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=0;i<x;i++) {
            if(a[i]<0) {
                a[i]=0;
            }
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");

        }
        for(i=0;i<x;i++) {
            if(a[i]!=0) {
                a[i]=b[i];
            }
            System.out.print(b[i]);
        }


        }
    }
}
```

This is how I did it but still in the second array where the zeroes should be eliminated , all are appearing zero.

Comment: the first array is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
import java.util.*;
class pr9
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x,i,j;
        int SECOND_ARRAY_SIZE = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter Length of the Array");
        x=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[x];

        for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter " +x+" Numbers");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            if(a[i] > 0)
                SECOND_ARRAY_SIZE++;
        }

        int b[]=new int [SECOND_ARRAY_SIZE];

        for(i = 0, j = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<0)
                a[i]=0;
            else if(a[i] > 0)
            {
                b[j] = a[i];
                j++;
            }
        }

        // Easier to read
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));

        // What you want
        for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
            System.out.print(a[k] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int l = 0; l < b.length; l++) {
            System.out.print(b[l] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow.. i can't believe i actually made such a silly mistake.. wow.. anyway thnx folks...

Comment: well need one more help.. both arrays are being printed on the same line.. how to print the b[] array in next line?

Comment: i changed to "b[i] = a[i]".. But the b[] array is showing the zeroes..I have to eliminate them

Comment: but i want the first a[] array to have the zeroes.. but i want to remove them in the second (b[]) array and i want to display both in different lines

Comment: If you follow my answer, you will end up with the first array **a[]** containing positive numbers & zeros instead of negatives, & a second array **b[]** that contains positives only. Check my edit for how to print them.

Comment: can u post how exactly would it look after editing with my syntax? I am not being able to understand which lines of mine to replace with your code. Help

Comment: @rockz3r 1 sec. Where is your `main` function ?

Comment: I am using calc() not main()        'code'                                             import java.util.*;
class pr9
{
    public static void calc()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x,i,j;
        System.out.println("Enter Length of the Array");
        x=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[x];
        int b[]=new int [x];
        for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter " +x+" Numbers");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt()                                                                             'code'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97771/discussion-between-rockz3r-and-sparta).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are assigning to the wrong array :

```
a[i]=b[i];
```

should be

```
b[count]=a[i]; // note the different index
```

Second of all, when you assign to the second array, you must have two counters, since `a[i]` will not necessarily be assigned to `b[i]`.

I suggest that you use the first loop to calculate how many non zero elements you have in the array, and create `b` with the correct length (otherwise it will contain 0s as its last elements) :

```
    int bLength = 0;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<0)
        {
            a[i]=0;
        } else {
            bLength++;
        }
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");

    }
    b = new int[bLength];
    int count=0;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=0)
        {
            b[count++] = a[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your problem.

```
   if(a[i]!=0) 
        {
            a[i]=b[i]; 
        }
        System.out.print(b[i]);
    }
```

b[] is never set so the values are all 0. You are checking each element of a[] and if its not equal to 0 you assign it to the value at b[] which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's say that a[] is the array that should hold all values greater or equal than 0. This should work.
Your first problem is that the array that should hold all the positive numbers is as big as the entered amount of numbers. That's in most cases to big.
But if it doesn't matters that there are empty indizes in the array, your code should work if you replace the second loop with

```
            if(a[i]!=0)
            {
                b[i]=a[i];
            }
```

You did it the wrong way round (a[i] = b[i]).